# Returning a variety of percentiles in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a piece of code which returns the 90th percentile of a group of data and I am trying to change the code to return other percentiles (25th, 50th, 75th). Here is the code which returns the 90th percentile (without interpolating) successfully:

```
SELECT Max ([Subquery]![RECP]) AS RECP90P
FROM (SELECT TOP 90 PERCENT [RECP] FROM [CompData Query] ORDER BY [RECP] DESC)  AS Subquery;
```

My thinking is that if I change the code to the following I would be able to return the 25th percentile, for instance. Here is what I've attempted:

```
SELECT Min ([Subquery]![RECP]) AS RECP25P
FROM (SELECT TOP 75 PERCENT [RECP] FROM [CompData Query] ORDER BY [RECP] DESC)  AS Subquery;
```

I know that there is no `SELECT BOTTOM` in SQL so I was attempting to return the inverse by using `MIN`. However, when I attempt to run this code I return a blank value. I tried changing `DESC` to `ASC` thinking that perhaps `MIN`was returning the *first* value and not the *minimum* of all values, but even this returned a blank value. Is anyone able to explain where I am going wrong?

Would something like this work instead?

```
SELECT Max([CompData Query]![AgedSalary]) CASE ([CompData Query]![Code]) WHEN "RECP" AS RECP90P
FROM (SELECT TOP 90 PERCENT [AgedSalary] FROM [CompData Query] ORDER BY [RECP] DESC)  AS Subquery;
```

Would you be able to explain why this `CASE WHEN`is wrong and/or missing an `Operator':

```
SELECT CASE ([CompData Query]![Code]) WHEN "RECP" THEN SELECT Max([CompData Query]![AgedSalary]) AS RECP90P FROM (SELECT TOP 90 PERCENT [AgedSalary] FROM [CompData Query] ORDER BY [AgedSalary] DESC) ELSE 'Unknown' END;
```

Thank you.

Comment: `RECP` has blank values in the column.  That is why you are getting them with the `MIN()`.

Comment: Do you know how to exclude blank values in an expression?

Comment: I think I probably need to use CASE WHEN in SQL to exclude the blanks

Comment: Just use a where clause to eliminate the rows you don't want. `WHERE RTRIM([REC]) <> '' Your case expression is wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Access has a TRIM() function but any of LTRIM, RTRIM, and TRIM should do what you want.

```
SELECT Min ([Subquery]![RECP]) AS RECP25P
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 75 PERCENT [RECP]
    FROM [CompData Query]
    WHERE RTRIM([RECP]) <> ''
    ORDER BY [RECP] DESC
)  AS Subquery;
```